# Suiting DataStructure for a Graph (own implementation)

Tags: c#, data-structures, graph

I am going to write my own Graph structure in C# (i know such exist but I want to practice + I need custom methods). The idea is simple:

1. The `Graph<T>` class will have a set of `GraphNode<T>` objects, representing the nodes
2. Each node will have a set of `GraphNode<T>` objects representing the nodes, to which it connects (oriented graph).

My question is simple: What datastructure should I use if I want fast traversal over the sets of `GraphNode<T>`? Fast adding/removing is +, but not a primary target.

Comment: Well, I think you pretty much already described it: each `GraphNode` will have a collection of its neighbor `GraphNode`s.

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking what datastructure should I use for that collection.

Comment: That depends on what kind of modifications are you going to make to that collection, but for common usage, `List<GraphNode<T>>` should do.

Comment: If I want the graph to be weighed, will `Dictionary<GraphNode<T>, double>` be a good choice (double will be the weight).

Answer (score 0):

If you expect a relatively small number of nodes (less then a hundred thousand), you could use an adjacency matrix (for larger number of nodes, you can use bitwise operators; this also depends on whether your graph is weighed). This would be very slow on insertion/deletion.

For fast graph traversal, a list of neighbor nodes would be useful as it can be traversed very quickly. Also, this approach would allow parallelization of the traversal, which would improve performance. This approach is probably the best for what you're looking for.

I would go with `List<GraphNode<T>>` for storing neighbors.
For a weighed graph with many nodes a `ConcurrentDictionary<GraphNode<T>, double>` should perform well.